# saving chat messages in MYSQL ID

Tags: mysql

im saving chat messages in MYSQL and set the ID for each message as an BIGINT AutoIncriment
is it wrong?
is the BIGINT gonna be enough, and what the solution if we reach the maximum number for BIGIN value?

Comment: How many chat messages will you insert per second? Do you increment the ID by 1 each time? Did you start the ID at 1? If so, you will not run out of a BIGINT before the sun explodes.

Comment: thanks someone edited the question and give a good link